# Visual studio 2012 deploy failed error 0x80131500

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I try to run my program I am getting deployment errors. Error code is 0x80131500.

I have tried creating a new project and running it. But it is again showing the same error.

Please suggest me a solution....

Thank you !

Comment: Does this help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a96c29d0-cbc0-4ffc-862a-1dbb10740329/visual-studio-exception-0x80131500

Comment: This is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62739672/ssis-failed-on-installation-for-vs-2019/69085239#69085239

Answer (score 0):

Try updating by going to extensions and updates, in tools, and updating to Visual Studio 2012 update 4 and then run the program.