# SSIS failed on installation for VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I'm able to install SSAS and SSRS for VS2019 but the big problem is that the SSIS fails in installation  and also i cannot know the error because it mentionned unknown error **result: 0x80131500** i have tried to uninstall vs2019 and reinstall it's still doing the same action
that's my log after failing again and again... please i need some help...

```
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:05:25]i325: Registering dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package: ISVsixPreInstall
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:05:25]i323: Registering package dependency provider: ISVsix, version: 1.0.0.0, package: ISVsix
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:05:25]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Projets Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (id: ISVsix)
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:05:25]i301: Applying execute package: ISVsix, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\VSIXBootstrapper.exe" /q /admin /instanceIds:"27dffa5e" /logFile:"C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20200705100315_2_ISVsix.log" "payload\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices.vsix"'
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:05:26]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 50, Overall progress: 62
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]e000: Error 0x80131500: Process returned error: 0x80131500
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to execute EXE package.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Projets Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (id: ISVsix)
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i319: Applied execute package: ISVsix, result: 0x80131500, restart: None
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]e000: Error 0x80131500: Failed to execute EXE package.
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: ISVsix, package: ISVsix
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsix, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\15160B731819F56D87A626F9A2777550340022D7\
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package ISVsixPreInstall
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Started for package Préinstallation de projets Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (id: ISVsixPreInstall)
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageActionProgress: Percent completed: 100, Overall progress: 75
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i301: Applying rollback package: ISVsixPreInstall, action: Uninstall, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\AC5949E416AE0F91550B518184F99F5ACD94CE95\ISVsixPreInstall.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\AC5949E416AE0F91550B518184F99F5ACD94CE95\ISVsixPreInstall.exe" /instanceIds:"27dffa5e" /log:"C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20200705100315_1_ISVsixPreInstall.log" /u'
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: MainViewModel.OnPackageAction: Install Completed for package Préinstallation de projets Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (id: ISVsixPreInstall)
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i319: Applied rollback package: ISVsixPreInstall, result: 0x0, restart: None
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: ISVsixPreInstall, package: ISVsixPreInstall
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i351: Removing cached package: ISVsixPreInstall, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\AC5949E416AE0F91550B518184F99F5ACD94CE95\
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {2DB3D120-4C41-47E8-99EE-54B6552D092A}, package SSDTISSingleton
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {2DB3D120-4C41-47E8-99EE-54B6552D092A}, package: SSDTISSingleton
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {A1EF85A7-37B3-459F-B9E8-2A235BD5E98F}, package SSDTISSingleton140
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {A1EF85A7-37B3-459F-B9E8-2A235BD5E98F}, package: SSDTISSingleton140
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {C49E181B-C19F-4A1F-BE76-D463E7E3B2B5}, package SSAS_OLEDB2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {C49E181B-C19F-4A1F-BE76-D463E7E3B2B5}, package: SSAS_OLEDB2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {97A881AD-5134-4CD2-A6A8-371C83E5622B}, package SSAS_AMO2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {97A881AD-5134-4CD2-A6A8-371C83E5622B}, package: SSAS_AMO2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {76CBDC35-0752-4B5A-83E8-49A741BD42BC}, package SSAS_AMO2014
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {76CBDC35-0752-4B5A-83E8-49A741BD42BC}, package: SSAS_AMO2014
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {53086A62-13F3-4FC5-AA41-211FD74340B3}, package SSAS_AMO2012
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {53086A62-13F3-4FC5-AA41-211FD74340B3}, package: SSAS_AMO2012
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {49CF853F-0D39-4E9C-9DFE-4680390C69F6}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_3082
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {AC773FDF-4E16-4D00-BA13-CC658CD58870}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_2052
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {4D24D1C9-F682-438F-BA38-EA9AEF5801EA}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1049
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {FEA2923C-9F89-429E-9B00-BB9BC6568AFD}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1046
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {6AC4A6E2-EF8C-4556-9D22-E3CCA2FFB315}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1042
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {9A66FE94-CABF-49A8-9628-45E256338B46}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1041
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {AEAD6F1E-83A4-437F-91A3-D23BAFFC3FC4}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1040
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {9A074F15-3BF4-4622-B6DE-64A0CC8BE233}, package SSISOneDesigner2016_1036
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {9A074F15-3BF4-4622-B6DE-64A0CC8BE233}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1036
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {22670E6E-F2F5-4CCB-B0E3-F610F48279D3}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1031
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {2EF802EE-97C3-4E4D-BBCC-F660D860B75E}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016_1028
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {1F86F7A6-BCC6-49C4-8033-785993FA6331}, package SSISOneDesigner2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {1F86F7A6-BCC6-49C4-8033-785993FA6331}, package: SSISOneDesigner2016
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {A80AF420-3D83-4B55-BFED-B8461A1C8D49}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_3082
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {C3EDDEE1-C6B8-448A-A07C-717AE879AFCE}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_2052
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {D8A09386-AAD3-4B19-87A5-F8DE5431F283}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1049
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {437A306D-C5EC-49F6-AC94-F942F5C10629}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1046
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {F4B02C3C-E6A3-4CD1-A4B6-EB31D3B3C775}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1042
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {455A11C1-2012-460E-8271-B65BCE743FE2}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1041
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {ED53498B-2A2D-4664-8C6A-6343DC308431}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1040
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {9460EFF8-3DC7-414C-8DCB-E3D8FD100A40}, package SSISOneDesigner2014_1036
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {9460EFF8-3DC7-414C-8DCB-E3D8FD100A40}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1036
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {E2373941-5862-489D-AD48-85CAEEF3CFA5}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1031
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i329: Removed package dependency provider: {0BB4850C-B30C-4165-8B76-5BA672673B18}, package: SSISOneDesigner2014_1028
[2658:0BF4][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i326: Removed dependency: {e36c6a2f-2029-4329-90b7-5fb4feb9102a} on package provider: {07001141-C74D-47ED-B03D-892C7EF00E3D}, package SSISOneDesigner2014
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Processing C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100355_06f8.log ...
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Copy C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100355_06f8.log to C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100355_06f8.log
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Processing C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100359_199c.log ...
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Either '' is empty or already exists. Skip copying.
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i000: TryCheckAndCopyVsixInstallerLog: Copy C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100359_199c.log to C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\dd_VSIXInstaller_20200705100359_199c.log
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: Unknown error (0x80131500) (0x80131500)
[278C:2788][2020-07-05T10:06:31]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80131500, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[278C:28D0][2020-07-05T10:06:36]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\BRIEDA\AppData\Local\Temp\SsdtisSetup\Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices_20200705100315.log
```

Comment: [I answered a similar question here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167815/3921617)

Comment: So how can we set this as duplicate @Bhargav Rao ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSDT Installation for VS2017 Team Explorer Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379647/ssdt-installation-for-vs2017-team-explorer-fails)